# dd copy a HDD to USB but fail to boot?

Tags: boot, usb, dd

```
dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdc bs=10M
```

`/dev/sdb` is a HDD with installed CentOS7 and able to boot.

if `/dev/sdc` is another HDD, the `dd` copy works OK, `/dev/sdc` can boot without problem.

if `/dev/sdc` is a USB disk, it can't boot after `dd` copy.

failed log ( when using USB disk as /dev/sdc )

```
dracut-initqueue[704]: calling: settle
dracut-initqueue[704]: calling: settle
dracut-initqueue[704]: calling: settle
...

/* log repeat and can't boot to os */
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the initramfs file does not include the `usb-storage` driver or one of its dependencies.

You could fix this before the `dd` copy by doing something like:

```
# dracut -–add-drivers usb-storage <your initramfs file>
```